# Trying to save multiple plots as individual files created through a function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2

I am creating a whole bunch of graphs through a function. I am trying to save them all individually. I have tried a for loop and it creates the right number of graphs and names them individually with the list i gave it but each graph is of the first plot in the list... what am doing wrong?

```
###Individual Facets
head(subsetLI15min)

single_facet_LI15 <- function(preserve){
  subsetLI15min %>% filter(Preserve_N == preserve) %>%
    gather(income,percent,inc0to10k:inc200plus) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= factor(income,level= c("inc0to10k","inc10to24K","inc25to34K","inc35to44K", 
                                         "inc45to59K","inc60to74k", "inc75to99k", "inc100to199K", "inc200plus")),
               y=percent,fill=income))+
    geom_bar(colour = "black",
             stat='identity')+
    ylim (0,40)+
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          #axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
    geom_text(aes(label = percent), 
              vjust=-0.25,
              size= 2.5)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues",
                      limits = c("inc0to10k","inc10to24K","inc25to34K",
                                 "inc35to44K", "inc45to59K","inc60to74k",
                                 "inc75to99k", "inc100to199K", "inc200plus"))+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("inc0to10k","inc10to24K","inc25to34K",
                              "inc35to44K", "inc45to59K","inc60to74k",
                              "inc75to99k", "inc100to199K", "inc200plus"),
                     labels=c("less than 10K","10K-24K","25K-34K","35k-44K",
                              "45K-59K","60K-74K","75K-99K","100K-199K","Over 200K"))+
  facet_wrap(~Preserve_N)}

# create a vector of all the preserves in your data, 

preserve_names_LI <- unique(subsetLI15min$Preserve_N) 

# take each element in .x (a preserve name in this case) and passes it one at a time to the funciton we made.

plots<- purrr::map(.x = preserve_names_LI, .f = ~single_facet_LI15(.x)) 

plots 

view(preserve_names_LI)

### save plots PDF 

for(x in preserve_names_LI){
  
  plots<- purrr::map(.x = preserve_names_LI, .f = ~single_facet_LI15(.x))
  
  pdf(paste(x,".pdf",sep=""))
  print(plots)
  dev.off()}
```

Comment: Trying using `ggsave` inside your function

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).